# What happens to the cache-lines for a page when the page is swapped out to the disk?

Tags: caching, operating-system, paging, cpu-architecture

When a page is swapped out to disk, some of its content might be present in a cache (I believe this would be a very rare scenario, because, if the page is not accessed for a long time, most likely the cache-lines containing its content would also have been evicted by then.) What happens to these cache-lines when the page is swapped out. Do they need to be invalidated immediately ? Does it make any difference if the line is dirty or clean ? Who controls this process, OS or hardware or both ?

To explain why this need be taken care of, lets assume there are processes A & B and A is accessing physical page P1 at starting physical address X. Some of the contents of P1 must have been cached in different levels of caches. Now the page P1 is swapped out and page P2 of process B is brought in at the same address X. So if the cache-lines belonging to page P1 are not invalidated, then process B might get caches hit on those lines which originally belonged to process A for page P1 (because the physical tag would match).

Is this scenario valid ? Does it make any difference if the cache is VIPT or PIPT ?

It would be great, if you can cite how it is handled in modern OS/Processor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If DMA (the preferred method of copying data between I/O devices and memory for large transfers) is cache coherent (i.e., the DMA agent checks the cache), then hardware will ensure that any dirty cache lines will be read when paging out and any old cache lines will be invalidated (or overwritten — some systems support I/O devices storing to cache). For non-coherent DMA, the OS would have to flush the page being paged out to memory.

Whether DMA is coherent is ISA and implementation dependent. For example, [this blog post](https://www.osr.com/blog/2014/04/04/dma-cache-coherent-arm/) mentions that x86 guarantees coherence but Itanium and ARM do not. (Note that an implementation of an ISA can provide stronger guarantees.)

Whether the cache is virtually indexed or not would not impact the operations required because the OS would flush based on the virtual address and aliasing issues would already be handled in hardware or by software (e.g., by page coloring).